# split view screen after login screen

Tags: ipad

I have a login screen after logging in it should be navigated to a split view. I have created a split view programmatically, and used two controllers left view controller(as table view) and right view controller(in which detail view is to be displayed)on another view controller but on click of left view  subview on right view controller is not generated.I am a novice in iPad and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the split view in appDelegate